# Rock-Paper-Scissors

Tags: java, rock-paper-scissors

I was given this exercise:

> Build a game in which two players compete in a game of
>   Rock-Paper-Scissors with different strategies. Who will win more
>   rounds? The rules:
>
> - Scissors beats Paper
> - Rock beat Scissors
> - Paper beats Rock
> - If both players choose the same, the round is counted as a tie.
>
> Implement two players:
>
> - Player A always chooses Paper
> - Player B chooses randomly
>
> The game consists of 100 rounds of above two players competing. The
>   output of the program should be like the following:
>
> ```
> "Player A wins 31 of 100 games"
> "Player B wins 37 of 100 games"
> "Tie: 32 of 100 games"
> ```

Here is my solution:

The moves:

```
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * The moves of a {@link Game}
 * 
 * @author ms
 *
 */
public enum Move {

    ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS;

    /**
     * Holds the moves a move beats
     */
    private static final Map<Move, Move>    beats   = new EnumMap<>(Move.class);

    // init the beats
    static {
        beats.put(ROCK, SCISSORS);
        beats.put(PAPER, ROCK);
        beats.put(SCISSORS, PAPER);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the move this move beats
     * 
     * @param m
     *            The current move
     * @return The move this move beats
     */
    public static Move beats(final Move m) {
        return beats.get(m);
    }

}
```

---

The players:

```
/**
 * The superclass of all players
 * 
 * @author ms
 *
 */
public abstract class Player {

    /**
     * Generates the next move
     * 
     * @return the next move
     */
    public abstract Move getNextMove();

}
```

---

```
/**
 * A player that always returns a {@link Move#PAPER} move
 * 
 * @author ms
 *
 */
public class PaperPlayer extends Player {

    @Override
    public Move getNextMove() {
        return Move.PAPER;
    }

}
```

---

```
import java.util.Random;

/**
 * A player that always returns a random move
 * 
 * @author ms
 *
 */
public class RandomPlayer extends Player {

    /**
     * Caches all values of {@link Move} for the random generator
     */
    private static final Move[] moves   = Move.values();

    /**
     * The random number generator used; created once and then cached
     */
    private final Random        generator;

    public RandomPlayer() {
        generator = new Random();
    }

    @Override
    public Move getNextMove() {
        return moves[generator.nextInt(moves.length)];
    }

}
```

---

The game:

```
import java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles;
import java.util.EnumMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

/**
 * A Game of rock-scissor-paper
 * 
 * @author ms
 *
 */
public class Game {

    private static final int    NUMBER_OF_GAMES = 100;

    private static final Logger logger          = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MethodHandles.lookup().lookupClass());

    /**
     * An enum encapsulating the results of one move which also holds the strings needed for
     * generating the output
     * 
     * @author ms
     *
     */
    enum Result {
        A_WINS("Player A wins "), B_WINS("Player B wins "), TIE("Tie: ");

        private final String    output;

        private Result(String output) {
            this.output = output;
        }

        public String getOutput() {
            return output;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final Player playerA = new PaperPlayer();
        final Player blayerB = new RandomPlayer();
        final Map<Result, Integer> results = new EnumMap<>(Result.class);

        initResults(results);
        playGame(playerA, blayerB, results);
        printResults(results);
    }

    /**
     * Initialize the {@code results} map with 0 values
     * 
     * @param results
     *            the inialized results map
     */
    private static void initResults(final Map<Result, Integer> results) {
        for (final Result r : Result.values()) {
            results.put(r, 0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Plays {@link #NUMBER_OF_GAMES} rounds of the game
     * 
     * @param playerA
     *            A player
     * @param blayerB
     *            A player
     * @param results
     *            The results are stored here
     * @see #playOneRoundOfTheGame(Player, Player, Map)
     */
    private static void playGame(final Player playerA, final Player blayerB, final Map<Result, Integer> results) {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_GAMES; i++ ) {
            playOneRoundOfTheGame(playerA, blayerB, results);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Plays one round of the game
     * 
     * @param playerA
     *            A player
     * @param blayerB
     *            A player
     * @param results
     *            The results are stored here
     * @see #playGame(Player, Player, Map)
     */
    private static void playOneRoundOfTheGame(final Player playerA, final Player blayerB,
            final Map<Result, Integer> results) {
        final Move moveA = playerA.getNextMove();
        final Move moveB = blayerB.getNextMove();
        final Result result = evaluateMoves(moveA, moveB);
        logger.debug("A: {}, B: {}. result: {}", moveA, moveB, result);
        results.put(result, results.get(result) + 1);
    }

    /**
     * Evaluates one round of the game
     * 
     * @param moveA
     *            The move of one player
     * @param moveB
     *            The move of another player
     * @return The {@link Result}
     */
    static Result evaluateMoves(final Move moveA, final Move moveB) {
        final Result result;
        if (Move.beats(moveA) == moveB) {
            result = Result.A_WINS;
        }
        else {
            if (Move.beats(moveB) == moveA) {
                result = Result.B_WINS;
            }
            else {
                result = Result.TIE;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Prints the results
     * 
     * @param results
     *            The results
     */
    private static void printResults(final Map<Result, Integer> results) {
        for (final Result r : Result.values()) {
            System.out.printf("%s %d of %d games%n", r.getOutput(), results.get(r), NUMBER_OF_GAMES);
        }
    }

}
```

---

A test:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameter;
import org.junit.runners.Parameterized.Parameters;

import Game.Result;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.*;

/**
 * @author ms
 *
 */
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class GameTest {

    @Parameters
    public static Iterable<Object[]> testData() {
        return Arrays.asList(new Object[][] { { Move.ROCK, Move.ROCK, Result.TIE },
                { Move.ROCK, Move.PAPER, Result.B_WINS }, { Move.ROCK, Move.SCISSORS, Result.A_WINS },
                { Move.PAPER, Move.PAPER, Result.TIE }, { Move.PAPER, Move.ROCK, Result.A_WINS },
                { Move.PAPER, Move.SCISSORS, Result.B_WINS }, { Move.SCISSORS, Move.SCISSORS, Result.TIE },
                { Move.SCISSORS, Move.ROCK, Result.B_WINS }, { Move.SCISSORS, Move.PAPER, Result.A_WINS }, });
    }

    @Parameter(0)
    public Move     moveA;

    @Parameter(1)
    public Move     moveB;

    @Parameter(2)
    public Result   expectedResult;

    /**
     * Test method for
     * {@link Game#evaluateMoves(Move, Move)}
     * .
     */
    @Test
    public void testEvaluateMoves() throws Exception {
        assertThat(Game.evaluateMoves(moveA, moveB)).isEqualTo(expectedResult);
    }

}
```

---

Pros:

- The logic of the game (which move beats which) is kept in one place (the 
  definition of Move), making it easy to replace the rules with e.g. 
  rock-paper-scissors-lizard-spock

Cons:

- The naming of the components feels too trivial
- The main loop in Game.playGame could probably be converted to using Java8 
  Streams/Lambdas, but this makes collecting the results more difficult

Only the evaluation of moves is tested, as this is the only non-trivial code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But I'm still interested in a Java8/Streams-solution. *– [@Martin Schröder](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90501/rock-paper-scissors#comment164127_90507)*

Hey... it's show-and-tell time!

### `Move`

```
enum Move {
    ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS;

    boolean beats(Move another) {
        switch (this) {
        case ROCK:
            return another == SCISSORS;
        case PAPER:
            return another == ROCK;
        case SCISSORS:
            return another == PAPER;
        // note: see alternative below
        default:
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        // alternatively, just throw here without the default case
        // throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}
```

As suggested by [@tim](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/90507/27975) and [@OldCurmudgeon](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/90536/27975), it will be nicer if a `Move` knows whether it beats another `Move`, instead of relegating that to a `static` method. However, my method differs by going for a `switch` statement instead of relying on a `static Map` for two reasons:

- I find that the logic is clearer to read.
- Any good IDE will helpfully suggest you to add `case`s for all your `enum` values.

If [Lizard and Spock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-paper-scissors#Additional_weapons) paid a visit to your game, the `Map` solution will require significant re-tooling, whereas... it's at least easier to refactor the `switch` statement to *prudently* take care of them, for starters.

**edit** The alternative `throw`-ing of `IllegalStateException` suggested by [@maaartinus](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90501/rock-paper-scissors/90552?noredirect=1#comment164289_90552) is nifty in the sense that any good IDE will also prompt you to add `case` clauses for new `enum` values, and you'll still get the exception thrown.

### `Player`

```
enum Player implements Iterator<Move> {
    A() {
        @Override
        public Move next() {
            return Move.PAPER;
        }
    }, B() {
        @Override
        public Move next() {
            return Move.values()[GENERATOR.nextInt(Move.values().length)];
        }
    };

    private static final Random GENERATOR = new Random();

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

[@OldCurmudgeon's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/90536/27975) actually had a revision on this implementation with the `Iterator` interface, but for some reason it's not there anymore. Anyways, I have chosen to model this as an `enum` since we know that there are *usually* only two players in RPS (discounting any hard-core [MMORPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massively_multiplayer_online_role-playing_game) - I just made that up), and this is also explicitly defined in the question.

I could do a `switch` too inside a common `next()` method implementation, but I thought I'll just use an overriding approach for a change. The other thing of note is the `throw`-ing of `UnsupportedOperationException()` in the `remove()` method: this is just good form.

### `Round`

```
private static final class Round {

    private final Move aMove;
    private final Move bMove;

    private Round(Move aMove, Move bMove) {
        this.aMove = aMove;
        this.bMove = bMove;
    }

    public Optional<Player> getWinner() {
        return aMove == bMove ? Optional.empty() :
            Optional.of(aMove.beats(bMove) ? Player.A : Player.B);
    }

    public static Round of(Player aPlayer, Player bPlayer) {
        if (aPlayer.hasNext() && bPlayer.hasNext()) {
            return new Round(aPlayer.next(), bPlayer.next());
        }
        throw new NoSuchElementException("No more moves by player "
                + (aPlayer.hasNext() ? Player.B : Player.A));
    }
}
```

Now this is where I differ significantly in the modeling, and also where the first Java 8 feature [`Optional`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) shows up.

Your `Result` is merely a... result of applying a function to two moves to know who won. That means given a `Result`, one does not know what are the inputs *resulting* in the outcome. The shortcomings are:

- You have to model a `Player` and its representation as a `Result` separately (see `PaperPlayer`/`Result.A_WINS` and `RandomPlayer`/`Result.B_WINS`).

  - More code, more places to change if I want to change my player strategy, names, or mapping external inputs into moves.
- Once you capture the results, you lose the inputs.

  - Subsequently, you cannot replay the game.
  - It also becomes easy to *lie* in code since you cannot re-compute the scores.

Hence, I went with capturing the inputs of a round of the game, simply called `Round`. All it captures are both moves, and calling `getWinner()` then applies said function to give us an `Optional<Player>`.

One nifty feature of using `Optional` here is that it allows us to model a tri-state: Either player has won, or there is a tie. This allows me to conveniently do away with using `null` and doing `null`-checks explicitly, or having to add code for a tri-value `enum` to model a tie scenario. I will touch on this a little more later, and if you think about it, a tie scenario itself is also a *result* of neither player winning. Therefore, in finding out the number of ties in a game, there is no hard requirement to store that with a tie representation, since the value can be computed.

There is a light sanity check inside the `static` `of()` method, to make full use of our `Player` class implementing an `Iterator` interface.

One more thing about your solution: Your use of `output` for each of your `Result` values is really just the required prefix to use when you are displaying the results. There is therefore little flexibility should the requirements change: e.g. change in names or pattern.

### `Game`

```
public final class Game {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_GAMES = 100;
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Game.class);

    private static Map<Player, Long> play() {
        return Stream.generate(() -> Round.of(Player.A, Player.B))
                .limit(NUMBER_OF_GAMES)
                .map(Round::getWinner)
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Optional::get,
                        () -> new EnumMap<>(Player.class), Collectors.counting()));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Player, Long> results = Game.play();
        int wins = results.values().stream().mapToInt(Long::intValue).sum();
        results.forEach((k, v) -> logger.info("Player {} wins {} of {} games", k, v,
                Integer.valueOf(NUMBER_OF_GAMES)));
        logger.info("Tie: {} of {} games", Integer.valueOf(NUMBER_OF_GAMES - wins),
                Integer.valueOf(NUMBER_OF_GAMES));
    }
}
```

1. [`Stream.generate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#generate-java.util.function.Supplier-) supplies us with an infinite sequential stream of `Round`s for us, which are constructed based on calling `Round.of(Player, Player)`.
2. This is limited by calling `limit(NUMBER_OF_GAMES)`.
3. We then have to determine our winners of each `Round` by calling, i.e. `map()`-ping, to its `getWinner` [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).
4. Now, since this is actually an `Optional` wrapper, we can `filter()` by calling its `isPresent()` method (again, another method reference).
5. Finally, we `collect()` our winners by doing a [`groupingBy()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.stream.Collector-) with the appropriate arguments, remembering to call `get()` first on our `Optional` wrapper in order to access the underlying winning `Player`.

Inside our `main()` method, we can count the number of wins first after calling `Game.play()`. That is done by performing a `sum()` on the [`IntStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) returned when we called `mapToInt()`. To display the required results, we only need to do a `forEach()` on the `Map` and 'consume' both the key and value accordingly. The last line displays the number of ties for us.

Comment: Nice. Just a note: I'd move `default: throw new IllegalStateException();` out of the switch, so that you get a warning, if a new enum value gets added (and you'll get the exception anyway).

Comment: @maaartinus Nice suggestion, will include that in. :)

Comment: I especially like your use of `Player implements Iterator<Move>`. I tried that route but couldn't work out a way of joining the two streams. Now I see how it can be done.

Comment: `Round` can not be `private static` if it's in a separate file.

Comment: One additional requirement: I need tests. Currently I can test `Move`, but obviously one wants tests for `Round` and possibly `Game`. Any idea how to add tests?

Comment: @MartinSchröder I don't think there's much to test for `Round`, unless you really want to test the `of(Player, Player)` method for throwing the `Exception` (updated post to use [`NoSuchElementException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html)).

Answer (score 10):

I like your code, it's mostly very readable and well structured.

Your `evaluateMoves` can be written a lot shorter by having multiple returns, and by using `if-elseif` instead of `if-else-if`:

```
static Result evaluateMoves(final Move moveA, final Move moveB) {
    if (Move.beats(moveA) == moveB) {
        return Result.A_WINS;
    } else if (Move.beats(moveB) == moveA) {
        return Result.B_WINS;
    } else {
        return Result.TIE;
    }
}
```

I would also think about restructuring your `Move` enum, so that you can write the much nicer `if (moveA.beats(moveB))`. This would also allow for easier addition of other objects than rock, paper, and stone.

I would also probably move the counting of results outside of `playOneRoundOfTheGame` (because it's not playing, it's counting). Either move it to the calling class, or - for cleaner code - create a separate `Result` class, which contains all the code that's currently mixed in with `Game` (such as the initialization, the adding, etc). Something like `result.addWin(Player)` would be a lot nicer than `results.put(result, results.get(result) + 1);`.

Comment: You can omit the`else`.

Comment: You can also just use two single if-statements for the first two conditions since you're returning from the method anyways when the conditions are truthy, and then what @heslacher said; omit the last else. So it becomes: `if (a) return a_win`, `if (b) return b_win`, `return tie`.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, `Move.beats` should not be static. But I'm still interested in a Java8/Streams-solution.

Answer (score 6):

This is well-written and considered code.

I will echo the other's suggestions.

1. Make your `Move` enum have a `beats` method.
2. Make a `Results` object that maintains the results.

Here's what's left after I've tinkered with it.

```
/**
 * The moves of a {@link Game}
 *
 * @author ms
 *
 */
public enum Move {

    ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS;

    /**
     * Holds the moves a move beats
     */
    private static final Map<Move, Move> beats = new EnumMap<>(Move.class);

    // init the beats
    static {
        beats.put(ROCK, SCISSORS);
        beats.put(PAPER, ROCK);
        beats.put(SCISSORS, PAPER);
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if this move beats
     *
     * @param other move to compare with.
     * 
     * @return true if this move beats the other.
     */
    public boolean beats(Move other) {
        return beats.get(this) == other;
    }
}

/**
 * The superclass of all players
 *
 * @author ms
 *
 */
public abstract static class Player {

    /**
     * Generates the next move
     *
     * @return the next move
     */
    public abstract Move getNextMove();

}

/**
 * A player that always returns a {@link Move#PAPER} move
 *
 * @author ms
 *
 */
public static class PaperPlayer extends Player {

    @Override
    public Move getNextMove() {
        return Move.PAPER;
    }

}

/**
 * A player that always returns a random move
 *
 * @author ms
 *
 */
public static class RandomPlayer extends Player {

    /**
     * Caches all values of {@link Move} for the random generator
     */
    private static final Move[] moves = Move.values();

    /**
     * The random number generator used; created once and then cached
     */
    private final Random generator;

    public RandomPlayer() {
        generator = new Random();
    }

    @Override
    public Move getNextMove() {
        return moves[generator.nextInt(moves.length)];
    }

}

/**
 * A Game of rock-scissor-paper
 *
 * @author ms
 *
 */
public static class Game {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_GAMES = 100;

    /**
     * An enum encapsulating the results of one move which also holds the strings needed for generating the output
     *
     * @author ms
     *
     */
    enum Result {

        A_WINS("Player A wins "), B_WINS("Player B wins "), TIE("Tie: ");

        private final String output;

        private Result(String output) {
            this.output = output;
        }

        public String getOutput() {
            return output;
        }
    }

    private static class Results {

        final ConcurrentMap<Result, Integer> results = new ConcurrentHashMap<>(new EnumMap<>(Result.class));

        private void result(Result result) {
            // Add one (to 0 if it's not present.
            results.put(result, results.computeIfAbsent(result, x -> 0) + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
            for (final Result r : Result.values()) {
                s.append(r.getOutput())
                        .append(results.get(r)).append(" of ")
                        .append(NUMBER_OF_GAMES)
                        .append("\r\n");
            }
            return s.toString();
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final Player playerA = new PaperPlayer();
        final Player blayerB = new RandomPlayer();
        final Results results = new Results();

        playGame(playerA, blayerB, results);
        System.out.println(results);
    }

    /**
     * Plays {@link #NUMBER_OF_GAMES} rounds of the game
     *
     * @param playerA A player
     * @param blayerB A player
     * @param results The results are stored here
     * @see #playOneRoundOfTheGame(Player, Player, Map)
     */
    private static void playGame(final Player playerA, final Player blayerB, Results results) {
        for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_GAMES; i++) {
            playOneRoundOfTheGame(playerA, blayerB, results);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Plays one round of the game
     *
     * @param playerA A player
     * @param blayerB A player
     * @param results The results are stored here
     * @see #playGame(Player, Player, Map)
     */
    private static void playOneRoundOfTheGame(final Player playerA, final Player blayerB,
            Results results) {
        final Move moveA = playerA.getNextMove();
        final Move moveB = blayerB.getNextMove();
        final Result result = evaluateMoves(moveA, moveB);
        //logger.debug("A: {}, B: {}. result: {}", moveA, moveB, result);
        results.result(result);
    }

    /**
     * Evaluates one round of the game
     *
     * @param moveA The move of one player
     * @param moveB The move of another player
     * @return The {@link Result}
     */
    static Result evaluateMoves(final Move moveA, final Move moveB) {
        final Result result;
        if (moveA.beats(moveB)) {
            result = Result.A_WINS;
        } else if (moveB.beats(moveA)) {
            result = Result.B_WINS;
        } else {
            result = Result.TIE;
        }
        return result;
    }
}

public void test() {
    Game.main(null);
}
```

I am no expert in streams so this may not be an ideal solution but here's a moderately streamed version.

Essentially, the game is a stream of `Play` objects which are evaluated, grouped by the result and counted into a Map.

Most of the streaming is in the `playGame` method.

```
/**
 * A Game of rock-scissor-paper
 *
 * @author ms
 *
 */
public static class Game {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_GAMES = 100;

    /**
     * An enum encapsulating the results of one move which also holds the strings needed for generating the output
     *
     * @author ms
     *
     */
    enum Result {

        A_WINS("Player A wins "), B_WINS("Player B wins "), TIE("Tie: ");

        private final String output;

        private Result(String output) {
            this.output = output;
        }

        public String getOutput() {
            return output;
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(final String[] args) {

        final Player playerA = new PaperPlayer();
        final Player blayerB = new RandomPlayer();

        playGame(playerA, blayerB);
    }

    /**
     * Represents one play of the game.
     */
    private static class Play {

        final Move a;
        final Move b;

        public Play(Move a, Move b) {
            this.a = a;
            this.b = b;
        }

    }

    /**
     * Evaluates one round of the game
     *
     * @param moveA The move of one player
     * @param moveB The move of another player
     * @return The {@link Result}
     */
    static Result evaluateMove(final Move moveA, final Move moveB) {
        final Result result;
        if (moveA.beats(moveB)) {
            result = Result.A_WINS;
        } else if (moveB.beats(moveA)) {
            result = Result.B_WINS;
        } else {
            result = Result.TIE;
        }
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * Plays {@link #NUMBER_OF_GAMES} rounds of the game
     *
     * @param playerA A player
     * @param playerB A player
     * @param results The results are stored here
     */
    private static void playGame(final Player playerA, final Player playerB) {
        Map<Result, Long> results = IntStream.range(0, NUMBER_OF_GAMES)
                // Make one play per round.
                .mapToObj(i -> new Play(playerA.next(), playerB.next()))
                // Evaluate that move to a Result
                .map(p -> evaluateMove(p.a, p.b))
                // Count each result
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(r -> r, Collectors.counting()));
        // Print them.
        printResults(results);
    }

    /**
     * Prints out the results.
     *
     * @param results
     */
    private static void printResults(Map<Result, Long> results) {
        StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
        for (final Result r : Result.values()) {
            s.append(r.getOutput())
                    .append(results.get(r)).append(" of ")
                    .append(NUMBER_OF_GAMES)
                    .append("\r\n");
        }
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}

public void test() {
    Game.main(null);
}
```

And your plan worked! This works fine.

```
public enum Move {

    ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS, LIZARD, SPOCK;

    /**
     * Holds the moves a move beats
     */
    private static final Map<Move, Set<Move>> beats = new EnumMap<>(Move.class);

    // init the beats
    static {
        // Smashes scisors, Vaporizes rock
        beats.put(SPOCK, EnumSet.of(SCISSORS, ROCK));
        // Cuts paper, Decapitates lizard
        beats.put(SCISSORS, EnumSet.of(PAPER, LIZARD));
        // Covers rock, Disproves Spock
        beats.put(PAPER, EnumSet.of(ROCK, SPOCK));
        // Crushes lizard, Breaks scisors
        beats.put(ROCK, EnumSet.of(LIZARD, SCISSORS));
        // Poisons Spock, Eats paper 
        beats.put(LIZARD, EnumSet.of(SPOCK, PAPER));
    }

    /**
     * Returns true if this move beats
     *
     * @param other move to compare with.
     *
     * @return true if this move beats the other.
     */
    public boolean beats(Move other) {
        return beats.get(this).contains(other);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Although IMHO `Result.result` is not a very good name. And `Result.toString` is a prime candidate for `Streams`.

Comment: @MartinSchröder - Trying to do a `Collector` into `Results` - still a bit of a newbie with streams but eager to practice.

Comment: Updated - slightly more streamified.

Comment: I didn't realize this till now, but Lizard and  Spock wouldn't have a nice time playing here as you cannot have duplicate keys (e.g. `beats.put(SPOCK, SCISSORS);`, `beats.put(SPOCK, ROCK);`)

Comment: @h.j.k. - Good call - I've changed it to a `Map<Move,Set<Move>>` to get around that.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is nice, but it could be much shorter and expressed as a function

- Enumerate the choices from 0-2 `(0: rock, 1: paper, 2: scissors)`
- Enumerate the scores column from 0-2 `(0: Tie, 1: Player A, 2: Player B)`

And voila, the function to determine where the point for the round should go:

```
int [] choices = {0,1,2}; // Rock, Paper, Scissors
int [] players = {0,1,2}; // Tie, Player A, Player B
int [] scores = {0,0,0};  // Scores table

int playerAChoice = ...; //get input from player A
int playerBChoice = ...; //get input from player B

//3 choices with wraparound effect
int winner_index = (3 + playerAChoice - playerBChoice) % 3 

scores[winner_index] += 1;
```

**Edit**: Explanation of why I chose to suggest this solution instead of enums. Rock paper scissors is a subtype of a balanced game type where each weapon (i.e. rock/paper/scissors) beats the same amount of weapons as all other weapons. This can be expanded with "lizard spock" for instance.

If you were to model this with enums...it will be a tedious and error-prone process. You would have to literally copy/paste the rules for each game and it would also not be flexible.

Now, if you were to compute this with math, this is much simpler. Actually, the rule I specified for rock-paper-scissors can be generalised even further. The rule for any such game can be modelled as follows (source: [wikipedia on additional weapons in roshambo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock-paper-scissors#Additional_weapons)):

```
Alternatively, the rankings in rock-paper-scissors-Spock-lizard may be modeled 
by a comparison of the parity of the two choices. If it is the same (two odd
numbered moves or two even-numbered ones) then the lower number wins, while if
they are different (one odd and one even) the higher wins.
```

Enums have their place in Java, but so does insight in the problem you are actually solving.

Comment: No. Java has Enums and more types than int and array. This is not C99.

Comment: Obviously. But RockPaperScissorsEnterprise is not always necessary (see: https://github.com/EnterpriseQualityCoding/FizzBuzzEnterpriseEdition)

Comment: I agree with @MartinSchröder.  We can call the choices also `beers`, the players `elephants` and the score we can call `pink`.  Code still works but where is the readability?

Comment: @chillworld I would disagree with the readability issue. It is fairly obvious that the code takes the input choices and evaluates a winner...and updates the scores accordingly. 

Is it really worse to have a mathematical expression calculate where the +1 goes rather than hardcode things like : `Move.ROCK, Move.ROCK, Result.TIE` ?

Comment: @MartinSchröder While I fully agree with you, it's useful to know, that such a simple solution exists. I'd also go for enums, but seeing that there's a simple numerical relationship between the values can help to solve more complicated problems. And in some rare cases, you may even have to resort to such primitive means because of performance requirements.

Comment: 3 + is not necessary because (3+a)%3 == a%3

Comment: `(-1)%3` in java gives `-1` and not `2`.

Comment: Best answer! For me the `enum` stuff is well known and everyone proposes it and what else. I'm using it and I like it, but I also see that mathematical insight is more important. +++ Here, I'd possibly use `enum`s, but with logic based on the formula using their `ordinal`s.